# Bash Script that downloads newest kernel

Tags: bash, linux-kernel

So I have a bash script I'm using in order to download and compile the newest kernel available. Part of my assignment is to check GPG keys, and have implemented the following snippet below in order to check the keys against the official keys. Yet I still get a bad source from the check, is the logic wrong?

I check GPG keys for `ccache` that I build from source...

```
# check for ccache  ############################################################

wget "https://github.com/ccache/ccache/releases/download/v3.7.11/ccache-3.7.11.tar.xz"
wget "https://github.com/ccache/ccache/releases/download/v3.7.11/ccache-3.7.11.tar.xz.asc"

if [[ $(gpg --verify ccache-3.7.11.tar.xz.asc ccache-3.7.11.tar.xz 2>&1 \
    | grep -c "Good signature .* \[ultimate\]") -lt 1 ]]; then
    echo "Error: invalid source"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Good Source"
fi
```

And also for my Git of kernel check. First I add the keys below:

```
if [ ! -d "$GPGKEYS" ]; then
  gpg2 --locate-keys "torvalds@kernel.org" "gregkh@kernel.org"
  for trusted in "torvalds@kernel.org" "gregkh@kernel.org"; do
    echo -e "5\ny\n" | gpg --command-fd 0 --expert --edit-key $trusted trust
  done
fi
```

And then I use this loop to check keys, but I still get invalid keys or bad source. What am I doing wrong?

```
git clone --branch v$V \
    'https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git'
cd linux-stable

if [[ $(git tag -v v$V 2>&1 \
    | grep -c "Good signature .* \[ultimate\]") -lt 1 ]]; then
    echo "Bad Source"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Good Source"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running all of your script on shellcheck.net first. From what I see, there is no problem with the syntax besides missing the `fi` in the portion of code where you "add the keys". This must be a logic error then, what exactly does `$(git tag -v v$V 2>&1 \ | grep -c "Good signature .* \[ultimate\]")` return?

P.S. I'm answering as I do not have enough rep to comment.

Comment: its answering  as bad source , when it should be answering good source